# Lost file extensions in Zend Studio 5.5.1 on Windows 7

Tags: file, zend-studio

I managed to get Zend Studio 5.5.1 running on Windows 7 by running in Vista compatibilty mode and it works fine, except, I have lost the file types/extensions

I can add them again and the editor will open them, but I dont have any code completion or code coloring or anything

Ive tried php, .php, *.php

Anyone come across this and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of putting up with this then finally posting on SO, I happen to find this:

http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=340

Works perfectly, took 10 seconds